# Cordova app on Android - Screen may not go to sleep

Tags: android, cordova, android-4.4-kitkat

I am using cordova to build an Application for Android. This application shall run in fullscreen mode, and the screen may never turn off. I have full root-control over the devices - all with Android 4.4 - , where the application is installed.

I have set

`Developer options -> Stay awake -> checked`

and in

`Display->Sleep`

I have set the highest value, which is 30 minutes. The devices are all attached to their power supply.

My **config.xml** looks like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.project.name" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>Project </name>
    <description>
      Project
    </description>
    <author email="my@email.com">
      Test
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
      <allow-intent href="market:*" />
      <splash src="res/screen/android/test.png" />
      <preference name="Fullscreen" value="true" />
      <preference name="KeepRunning" value="true"/>
      <preference name="InAppBrowserStorageEnabled" value="true"/>
      <preference name="LoadingDialog" value="Application is loading"/>
      <preference name="ErrorUrl" value="error.html"/>
      <preference name="LogLevel" value="VERBOSE"/>
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>

</widget>
```

My Problem is, that the screen goes darker (not completely off), after the time that I have set in the display-options. E.g. the screen stays bright for 30 minutes, and after that it indeed stays on, but with very dark backlight.

**What can I do, that the screen stays bright?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found a plugin, that did the trick for me:

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Insomnia-PhoneGap-Plugin.git
```

then in Javascript:

```
window.plugins.insomnia.keepAwake()
```

Works like expected, screen stays always on.